# how to search without writing the whole word

Tags: sqlite

how to search without writing all the word
i want when the user enter the type if he write like two letter to show the Suggested results
my project is an app for a pharmacy and you can inseart the medicine then show it in another activity
also you can delete the medicine from the list and the dataBase
this is my dataBase code

```
data class MedicineModel (val id:Int , val name:String , val quantity :Int , val price:Double , val type:String )
class DataBase(context: Context):SQLiteOpenHelper(context , DataBase_Name , null , DataBase_Version) {
    var dataBase :SQLiteDatabase
    companion object{
        var DataBase_Name = "Pharmacy.db"
        var DataBase_Version = 1
        var Table_Name = "Medicine"
        var Col_ID = "id"
        var Col_NAME = "name"
        var Col_QUANTITY = "quantity"
        var Col_PRICE = "price"
        var Col_TYPE = "type"
    }
    init {
        dataBase = this.writableDatabase
    }
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        db!!.execSQL("Create Table $Table_Name ($Col_ID INTEGER primary key Autoincrement, $Col_NAME Text Not Null ," +
                " $Col_QUANTITY Integer Not Null , $Col_PRICE Double Not Null ,$Col_TYPE Text Not Null )")
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db!!.execSQL("Drop Table if exists $Table_Name")
        onCreate(db)
    }
    fun AddMedicine(name: String , quantity: Int , price: Double ,type: String ):Boolean{
        var cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(Col_NAME , name)
        cv.put(Col_QUANTITY , quantity)
        cv.put(Col_PRICE , price)
        cv.put(Col_TYPE, type)
       return dataBase.insert("$Table_Name" , null , cv) >0
    }
    fun ShowAllMedicines():ArrayList<MedicineModel>{
        var medicines = ArrayList<MedicineModel>()
        var c = dataBase.rawQuery("Select * From $Table_Name" , null)
        c.moveToFirst()
        while (!c.isAfterLast){
            var s = MedicineModel(c.getInt(0) , c.getString(1) ,c.getInt(2)
                , c.getDouble(3) , c.getString(4))
            medicines.add(s)
            c.moveToNext()
        }
        c.close()

        return medicines
    }
    fun SearchMedicines(type: String):ArrayList<MedicineModel>{
        dataBase = this.readableDatabase
        var medicines = ArrayList<MedicineModel>()
        var c = dataBase.rawQuery("Select * From $Table_Name where $Col_TYPE = '$type' ", null)
        c.moveToFirst()
        while (!c.isAfterLast){
            var s = MedicineModel(c.getInt(0) , c.getString(1) ,c.getInt(2)
                , c.getDouble(3) , c.getString(4))
            medicines.add(s)
            c.moveToNext()
        }
        c.close()

        return medicines
    }

    fun deleteMedicine (id: Int):Boolean{
        return dataBase.delete( Table_Name , "$Col_ID = $id" ,null ) >0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `LIKE` along with the `%` wild character e.g.

```
Select * From $Table_Name where $Col_TYPE LIKE '%$type%'
```

So if the value of type passed were **a** then rows such s **a**bcdef cde**a**fg would be returned.

You should note that it is recommended to bind parameters (i.e. to use a ? as the placeholder and pass the values via the 2nd parameter of the rawQuery function) to prevent SQL Injection.

e.g.

```
var c = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $Table_Name WHERE $Col_TYPE LIKE '%'||?||'%'", arrayOf(type))
```

- noting that the bound value is enclosed and in this usage the need to concatenate the wild characters using the  `||` operator.